# How to use strategy function Decorator in Draft.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I've been playing with the Decorators in Draft.js but when I could not build a custom one 
I am sending the text to an API which I will get  a response with an array of incorrect words that typed in the editor So I am trying to build a Strategory function that applies a style to all the items in that array

```
 function highlightWorngWords(contentBlock, callback) {
    let text = contentBlock.getText();
    let worngWords = ['word', 'word1' , 'word2'];
    while ( worngWords  !== null ) {
      start = worngWords.index;
      callback(start, start + worngWords[0].length);
    }  
  }
```

What did I miss it won't work?

Comment: did you add a component to style it https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-decorators#compositedecorator

Comment: Yes I did that, my problem is with Strategy function only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function highlightWorngWords(contentBlock, callback) {
    let text = contentBlock.getText();
    let worngWords = ['word', 'word1' , 'word2'];
    worngWords.forEach(word => {
      start = text.indexOf(word);
      if (start !== -1) {
         callback(start, start + word.length);
      }
    })
  }
```

Are you wanting to do something like this?

Comment: Hey Ben, this solution will highlight only the first match and it will stop for example if I have  " word word "only first word will highlight, How can I make the code looks for rest of matches?